# MYSQL query help (EAV Table)

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have the following query to retrieve customers who answer YES to a particular question "**OR**" NO to another question.

```
SELECT customers.id
FROM customers, responses
WHERE (
(
responses.question_id = 5
AND responses.value_enum = 'YES'
)
OR (
responses.question_id = 9
AND responses.value_enum = 'NO'
)
)
GROUP BY customers.id
```

Which works fine. However I wish to change the query to retrieve customers who answer YES to a particular question "**AND**" answer NO to another question.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

PS - The responses above table is in an EAV format ie. a row represents an attribute rather than a column.

Comment: How does your query work without a join condition? Perhaps you could post your table definitions?

Comment: In your example you don't appear to be joining between the customers and responses tables. This will be generating Cartesian results as you have written it - is this intentional?

Comment: can't you just change the OR to AND

Comment: @Jeff V: No, that wouldn't work. `responses.question_id` can't be equal to 5 and 9 at the same time.

Comment: I was thinking the same as Jeff V, I am surprised that other people actually understood the question in a different way.

Comment: @Mark Byers - your right!  I guess I need more coffee!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a column called customer_id in your responses table. Try joining the responses table to itself:

```
SELECT Q5.customer_id
FROM responses Q5
JOIN responses Q9 ON Q5.customer_id = Q9.customer_id AND Q9.question_id = 9
WHERE Q5.question_id = 5
AND Q5.value_enum = 'YES'
AND Q9.value_enum = 'NO'
```

Comment: +1 this is a lot more simple than how I was thinking to do it.  Nice.

Comment: Yep that returns the same result for me as Donnie's query. The help here is great can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately as such:

```
SELECT distinct
  c.id
FROM 
  customers c
WHERE
  exists (select 1 from responses r where r.customer_id = c.id and r.response_id = 5 and r.value_enum = 'YES')
  and exists (select 1 from responses r2 where r2.customer_id = c.id and r2.response_id = 9 and r2.value_enum = 'NO')
```

I made an assumption on the missing `join` condition, modify as correct for your schema.